# Select into table in another database that is password protected?

Tags: vb6, passwords, connection-string, ms-access-2003

In Microsoft Access 2003 and Visual Basic 6 I'm trying to copy a table to another access database that is password protected like this...

```
Select * INTO table2 IN 'database2.mdb' [;Password=TestPass] From table1
```

It fails with error : **Not a valid password**

Does the Select INTO format not accept the password with the mdb, and the password has to be in a connection string?  If not, how do you reference a different connection string/database?

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have no control over it, but if you do, you should know that database passwords serve no really useful purpose -- they are little more than "security theater." If you can remove the password, I'd recommend you do. If you're concerned about security, you're only fooling yourself if you think a database password addresses anything but the most trivial security concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * INTO Table2 IN '' [MS Access;PWD=TestPass;DATABASE=C:\Docs\database2.mdb]
FROM Table1
```

These days I would be more inclined to use something like the line below, it gives more control and allows for different back-ends:

```
SELECT * INTO Table2 FROM [MS Access;PWD=password;DATABASE=C:\Docs\database2.mdb].Table1
```

You can put any valid connection string between the square brackets.

Reference: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: You mean: `SELECT * INTO [;PWD=TestPass;DATABASE=C:\Docs\database2.mdb].table2 FROM table1`?

Comment: can't get either of these 2 to work.  I'll try and follow up with more info...  thanks

Comment: I tested the SQL above in the query design window of Access.

Comment: If the source and destination databases have same table names , what will be the change?

Answer (score 3):

If doesn't work this

```
SELECT * INTO [;PWD=TestPass;DATABASE=C:\Docs\database2.mdb].table2 FROM table1
```

Try to add `""` like this

```
SELECT * INTO [";PWD=TestPass;DATABASE=C:\Docs\database2.mdb"].table2 FROM table1
```

It worked for me (Delphi with jet SQL)