# SELECT INTO query error "must contain at least one table or query"

Tags: sql, delphi, ado

This old app is a db front end to desktop Jet database, Access 2000 file format.

- Delphi 2007
- TADOConnection.Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.
- TADOCommand

Originally the database did not have a password. The client wanted the db password protected to keep out prying eyes (yes, it is false security).

Now I have this frustrating problem with the SELECT INTO SQL for copying data to a new table within a separate archive database.

This function worked previously, but after adding a password to the db it returns "EOleException", "Query input must contain at least one table or query".

The code below contains the original working Jet SQL.

```
var
   dbNameArch, dbNameInt, tblName, IntDataSource, cs1 : string;
const
  SProvider = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=';
  SPassword = 'Password=' + '''xxxxxxxxx''';
begin
  dbNameArch := PathToArchive + 'archive.mdb';
  dbNameInt := PathToDb + 'active.mdb';
  tblName := CreateTableName;

  IntDataSource :=SProvider + dbNameInt + ';Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database '+ SPassword;
  ADOConnection2.ConnectionString := IntDataSource;
  ADOConnection2.LoginPrompt := False;
  ADOCommand2.Connection := ADOConnection2;

  try
      // ORIGINAL working query before password added
      // cs1 := 'SELECT * INTO ' + tblName + ' IN "'+ 
      //         dbNameArch + '" FROM Interventions WHERE InterDate < #' + 
      //         cxDateEditStart.Text + '#';

      // NEW query with password throws error
      cs1 := 'SELECT * INTO ' +  tblName + ' IN "' + 
              dbNameArch + '"' + SPassword + ' FROM Interventions WHERE InterDate < #' + 
              cxDateEditStart.Text + '#';

      ADOCommand2.CommandText := cs1;
      ADOCommand2.Execute;
  except
      on E : Exception do
         begin
            strTemp := 'Unable to create archive table.' + #13 + #13 +
                       E.ClassName + ' error with message:' + #13 +
                       E.Message;
            MessageDlg('Archive error', strTemp, mtError, [mbOK], 0, dckActiveForm);
            ADOConnection2.Close;
            Exit;
         end;
  end;

... etc.
```

The length of the failed query string (cs1) is 197 characters, is it too long?

I'm at my wit's end, can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt this due to Delphi Code, its the formatting of SQL Statement.   The following question most likely answers your syntax prolem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639086/select-into-table-in-another-database-that-is-password-protected

Comment: Yes Robert I agree that it's the formatting of the SQL (hence the sql tag). The problem I'm having is translating VB/VBA code into something acceptable to Delphi.

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked! `cs1 := 'SELECT * INTO [";PWD=' + strPassword + ';DATABASE=' + dbNameArch + '"].' + tblName + ' FROM Interventions WHERE InterDate < #' + cxDateEditStart.Text + '#';`

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I searched this web site for the past 2 days trying to find an answer. I guess I need lessons on how to search here.